# How to output always the same size (width/height) graph in R?

Tags: r, graph

When I output the graph in R, the size (width and length) is always changing. So whenever I output graphs, I change the size by myself.

For example, I need a consistent graph size to insert into my document, but sometimes the default value of width and height is not the same when I try to export, particularly on different PC. How can I fix W:500. H:400 graph size all the time?

Many thanks!!

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to use `ggsave` for exporting your plots. And if you want always the same sizes you can write a wrapper function which sets the width and heights to your personal defaults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get consistency, you should set the size of the graphics device yourself before plotting. For example, in Windows, you can use

```
windows(width=5.5, height=5, title="Controlled Size")
## NOW make your plot
```

to get a window that is always 5.5 inches wide by 5 inches high.

Other devices use minor variations for setting the size. You can check out other devices by looking at the help page  `help(Devices)`

For example,  bmp, jpeg, png and tiff allow you to set the number of pixels, not just the number of inches.

Comment: I forgot to say Thank you. Thanks to you, I'm making good graphs using windows(). Many thanks!!